# missing pictures/videos from HTC EVO after being encrypted

Tags: encryption, htc-evo

I have an HTC EVO.  It's been encrypted at work.  Afterwards, all of my pictures/videos are missing from my gallery, everything else is still there.  How do I get them back?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible (almost certain) that during the encryption process, they low level formatted your SD card which would make recovering your gallery items impossible at this point. They should have allowed you to backup your data before doing the encryption and/or made a backup of the device before they did the encryption. Might I suggest you ask them if they kept a backup before doing the encryption, that would be your only option at this point to get them back. Sorry.